# Colorising a table based on the content

Tags: tables, color

It can be hard for humans to recognise strings of numbers as being the same.

Consider the table below
[image: uncolored table]

If cells that had the same content were each colours the same,
then it is much more clear.
Cells with content that is not repeated wouldn't need colouring.

See the difference? it is much clearer that most entries occur repeat, and that many repeat 3 or 4 times.
[image: colour table]
The table above has been coloured roughly by hand in paint, to illustrate the point.
It could be done far better, and with much better more readable friendly colours

How can I create such a coloured table, automatically?

I don't mind if the solution uses Lua or PGF etc.

Comment: There's a few questions on this site about this -- search for colormap pgfplotstable to get started :)